# Vue js - v-on:change doesn't get current value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to show address every time it changes in `Google Maps Autocomplete` input.

The problem is that it does work only when I'm typing the text. When it shows options and I choose one of the addresses, it does not write the address.

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group form-group-default">
         <label for="maps_autocomplete">Adresa</label>
         <input type="text" id="maps_autocomplete" class="form-control" v-model="address">
    </div>
</div>

address:[[address]]

<script>
        var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                address: '',
                business_type_text: '',
            },
            methods: {}
        });
</script>
```

How to make it react on choosing maps option?

**EDIT**

I tried to use `change` event:

```
<input type="text" id="maps_autocomplete" class="form-control" v-bind:value="address" v-on:change="address = $event.target.value">
```

Which works when I choose option, but it writes only the characters type inside the input, not the whole address.

So if I write:

```
"Wash"
```

And I select:

```
"Washington"
```

It shows just "address:Wash"

Comment: Are you using a wrapper like this? https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete

Comment: @gilango No I don't I thought that I could do that without it but I will check the wrapper, thanks.

Comment: Have you try using vue watchers https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html ?